# asp with javascript

Tags: asp.net

Hi guys i have a javascript function:

```
function saveClose()
    {
        getSelectedDates();
        var test = document.getElementById('<%=hiddenInput.ClientID%>');
        if (test.value != 'false')
        {
            showYesNo('Save/Close', 'Would you like to save and close this Campaign?');
            document.getElementById('popupControl').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('divEntryMain').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('divBuilderMain').style.display = 'none';
        }
        else
        {
            showOk('Save/Close', 'Please fill in all mandatory fields');
            document.getElementById('popupControl').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('divEntryMain').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('divBuilderMain').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

and i want to execute this function in my code behind button click even..but it has to be executed after the code in the code behind..please assist..
My code behind button click..

```
protected void btnSaveClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Page.IsCallback || Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] arguments = Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"].Split(',');
            if (arguments.Length == 2)
            {
                GetDataFromFileds(Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"].Split(','));
            }
            return;
        }

    }
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Register a startup script after your event handler has run with Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx

```
protected void btnSaveClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Page.IsCallback || Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string[] arguments = Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"].Split(',');
        if (arguments.Length == 2)
        {
            GetDataFromFileds(Request.Params["__EVENTARGUMENT"].Split(','));
            //assuming reaching this point means success
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), 
                                                    "MyScript", 
                                                    "saveClose();",
                                                    true);
        }
        return;
    }

}
```

Comment: this is not working for me..the javascrit function does not get called

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the method from javascript, rather than add it to the page dynamically through server side code, check out [this article](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function.1).  In your javascript function you can call "_doPostBack" and target a specific event.